# Downloading the Dart SDK using the BITS service failed, retrying with WebRequest.?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

[image]
**What's the solution!**

I already have the latest version of Dart !

You set the path !

**message erorr**

```json
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This is a file transfer that uses the Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS).

+ CategoryInfo

: ObjectNotFound: (fluter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId:

CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\ROYAL2> flutter

Checking Dart SDK version...

Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 1cc4b2d280f5705c7901c10676eae8bdb3142631...

Downloading the Dart SDK using the BITS service failed, retrying with WebRequest...
```